# SQL statement: insertion for all ids from a given table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql statement below that creates a single mapping between a store id and an id for "mytest-0" from a another table. That does work for STOREID=16, but the trouble is that I have 100 store ids, and would have to repeat the statement 100 times. Is there a way to cover **all** 100 STOREID from STORE table? Also, the STOREIDs are not neat number going from 1 to 100, but various number starting at 16 and ending at 547. This is for an Oracle db.

```
insert into MAPPING (MAPPINGID, STOREID, GARMENTID, LASTMODIFIEDDATE)
values (MAPPINGID_SEQ.nextval, 16, (select g.GARMENTID from GARMENT g where UPPER(g.GARMENTNAME) = UPPER('mytest-0')), SYSDATE);
```

Would very much appreciate some help here. I dont know if what I'm asking is actually possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM` the store table.

Assuming the store table is called `store` and the ID column is `storeid`:

```
INSERT INTO mapping
            (mappingid,
             storeid,
             garmentid,
             lastmodifieddate)
            SELECT mappingid_seq.nextval,
                   s.storeid,
                   g.garmentid,
                   sysdate
                   FROM store s
                        LEFT JOIN garment g
                                  ON upper(g.garmentname) = upper('mytest-0');
```